# Taking unblurry pictures with Parkinson on Android

Tags: android, photography

I am looking for an Android application that would allow a user with Parkinson to take unblurry pictures. Gratis is better but not necessary.

Comment: Could it be an option to take picture with a timer, and something like a gorilla tripod? I guess the users main problem is shaking?

Comment: @holroy The issue is indeed shaking. Tripod is a way around but sometimes not very convenient :/

Comment: To avoid shaking you have three option,  as far as I know: 1) tripod,  2) fast shutter times,  or 3) multiple exposures and choosing the best.  I think timer and tripod is the better option... But let us see if someone has a better solution

Comment: Some camera apps have such a feature indeed IIRC: you push the shutter, and it takes a pic as soon as it's half-way "stable". I just don't remember where I've seen that when building up my [corresponding app list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_camera). E.g. [Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera) mentions "Option to auto-stabilize so your pictures are perfectly level no matter what". Given it's Almalence behind that one, I'm willing to believe this. Not tried it, though (the feature I mean; the app is good).

Comment: I have used a Sony DSC-TX10 digital camera (not an app) that has an *Anti Motion Blur* mode. It works amazing well if the subject or photographer are in motion (or both!).  I have yet to determine exactly how it works, but I believe it may take several photographs in rapid succession to determine what is signal vs. noise, and then compose a single image consisting of only the signal.  Perhaps there is a similar app available, or perhaps people with Parkinson's will be interested in that camera or a newer model.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Thanks, good to know!

Comment: Some android phones come with camera apps that control shutter speed, but you can get one from the apps store.  The shutter speed set at 1/500 or 1/1000th blur should be gone.  You will probably have to turn the ISO up and adjust the aperture size to avoid dark pictures.  Turning the ISO to high makes the picture grainy.

Comment: Not a software solution, but perhaps worth mentioning: some Android devices have physical self-stabilizing cameras, such as the Nexus 5. (The whole camera moves a millimetre or two, within a mount on the circuit board.) I find it pretty effective, but I am not living with PD.

Answer (score 2):

You need an application that has the following features:

- **Burst mode**: takes a series of pictures very quickly
- **Sport** or **high speed mode**: reads pictures very quickly

I recommend the app [**High-Speed Camera (GIF,Burst)**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hantor.CozyCamera&hl=en):

> 1. Supports high-speed shots (Up to 40 FPS).
>
> - Faster than normal DSLR camera.
> - Supports preview or auto save for burst shots.